# Project running on local server (WAMP) but on live server Error: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, path, require-once

I know, that's stupid, but I can't solve the problem with my project.

I wrote project on WAMP firstly and all works.

After, I try to migrate on live server, and find a problem - server don't require my files.

Project structure is:

```
application
  core
     Controller.php
     Model.php
     View.php
     Route.php
  models
  views
  controllers
  included
  config.php
  app.php
index.php
```

when I try to run it, server return error:

> Warning: require_once(core/model.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /home/u224052355/public_html/application/app.php
>   on line 4

This is the app.php code:

```
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'core/model.php';
require_once 'core/view.php';
require_once 'core/controller.php';
require_once 'core/route.php';
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){
    include 'included/' . $class_name . '.php';
});
Route::start();
```

When I try solve this by adding `__DIR__` to require_once I gave this message:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/u224052355/public_html/application/core/model.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u224052355/public_html/application/app.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/u224052355/public_html/application/core/model.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in
>   /home/u224052355/public_html/application/app.php on line 4

Using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and etc. - same result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you copied all the folder and files to the new server?

Comment: try using `require_once './core/model.php';` to see if that works

Comment: Yes, I copied all files (just zip all files on my local server)

Comment: I'm tried. Result: Warning: require_once(./core/model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u224052355/public_html/application/app.php on line 4

Comment: You could try to delete the cache etc. from your browser. I've had something similar to this and it worked for me.

Comment: Before any calls to either `include` or `require` try setting the `include_path` using `set_include_path` to the root directory rather than the default directories expected by PHP

Comment: In index.php require_once works. It doesn't work in app.php